# Threads and access to a shared list

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I'm encountering (I hope) a deadlocking issue with a WCF service I'm trying to write.

I have the following lock on a function that "locates" a particular item im the list:

```
 CIPRecipe FindRecipe_ByUniqueID(string uniqueID)
    {
        lock (_locks[LOCK_RECIPES])
        {
            foreach (var r in _recipes.Keys)
            {
                if (_recipes[r].UniqueID == uniqueID)
                {
                    return _recipes[r];
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

However, various functions reiterate through this list and always apply the same LOCK for example ....

```
 lock (_locks[LOCK_RECIPES_NO_ADD_OR_REMOVE])
            {
                foreach (var r in _recipes)
                {
                    r.Value.UpdateSummary();
                    summaries.Add((RecipeSummary)r.Value.Summary);
                }
            }
```

What I suspect is,  an item in _recipes in the above example has suddenly called a function which ultimately calls the first function - "CIPRecipe FindRecipe_ByUniqueID(string uniqueID)" and this is causing a deadlock when it is reached in the iteration.

I need to stop this list changing whilst I'm iterating through it. Can someone advise me the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: You should look in to `ReaderWriterLockSlim`

Comment: Thank you, please upgrade your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.
Don't know why the question received a downvote though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, this will let unlimited concurrent readers through but only a single writer through and block all readers while the writer is writing.

This assumes `_locks` has been chagned from a `object[]` to a `ReaderWriterSlim[]`

```
//On Read
CIPRecipe FindRecipe_ByUniqueID(string uniqueID)
{
    var lockObj = _locks[LOCK_RECIPES];
    lockObj.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        foreach (var r in _recipes.Keys)
        {
            if (_recipes[r].UniqueID == uniqueID)
            {
                return _recipes[r];
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        lockObj.ExitReadLock();
    }
    return null;
}

//On write
var lockObject = _locks[LOCK_RECIPES]; //Note this now uses the same lock object as the other method.
lockObj.EnterWriteLock();
try
{
    foreach (var r in _recipes)
    {
        r.Value.UpdateSummary();
        summaries.Add((RecipeSummary)r.Value.Summary);
    }
}
finally
{
    lockObj.ExitWriteLock();
}
```

I don't know if it will solve your deadlock issue, if it is caused by you allowing reads during a write it may.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's  much better solution that just using "lock (lockObject)", although I've used TryEnterWriteLock, TryEnterReadLock as an added check.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a ConcurrentDictionary is called for here?

Comment: Thanjs Hugh, I wasn't aware of this class but it's perfectly suited to what I need.